# Two conditional clause count in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df which looks like this:

```
api_spec_id  type_of_change   label
213              Breaking      NaN
213              Breaking      major
213              Non-Breaking  patch
345              Non-Breaking  NaN
345              Non-Breaking  patch
345              Non-Breaking  patch
678              Breaking      NaN
678              Breaking      minor
678              Breaking      major
123              Breaking      NaN
123              Breaking      NaN
```

I want to calculate the unique number of `api_spec_id` where:

all `type_of_change` are breaking, where expected output would be 2 (ids: 678,123)

all  `type_of_change` are non-breaking, where expected output would be 1 (id:345)

at least one `type_of_change` is breaking, expected output: 3 (ids:213,678,123)

at least one `type_of_change` is non-breaking, expected output: 2 (ids:213,345)

I am not sure how I can achieve this, any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the expected output. Do you want api_spec_id wise count of Breaking -Major ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution :

```
from functools import partial

grp = df.groupby("api_spec_id")

def detect(g, how, change):
    if how == "all":
        return g["type_of_change"].eq(change).all()
    elif how == "any":
        return g["type_of_change"].eq(change).any()

def get_id(df):
    return df["api_spec_id"].unique().tolist()
    
v1 = grp.filter(partial(detect, how="all", change="Breaking")).pipe(get_id)
v2 = grp.filter(partial(detect, how="all", change="Non-Breaking")).pipe(get_id)
v3 = grp.filter(partial(detect, how="any", change="Breaking")).pipe(get_id)
v4 = grp.filter(partial(detect, how="any", change="Non-Breaking")).pipe(get_id)
```

Output :

```
print(v1) # [678, 123]
print(v2) # [345]
print(v3) # [213, 678, 123]
print(v4) # [213, 345]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly, I am not able to award the bounty due to some restriction, but I will as soon as they open!

Comment: You’re welcome but If you can cancel the bounty, no need for it ;)

Answer (score 2):

We can do that by grouping by the `api_spec_id` and label, then applying a lambda function that skips the first element for each group, then we create a new column indicating where `label == 'major'` and `type_of_change == 'Breaking'`.

To get the counts of each `api_spec_id` we can use `groupby` again, then we can iterate over the unique label values with the same process. Here is the code below, dont forget to replace `'Breaking'` with `'Non-Breaking'` and other label types.

edit: based on your comments, now we will group by `api_spec_id` and then check the unique values of `type_of_change` within each group

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "api_spec_id": [213, 213, 213, 345, 345, 345, 678, 678, 678, 123, 123],
    "type_of_change": ["Breaking", "Breaking", "Non-Breaking", "Non-Breaking", 
                       "Non-Breaking", "Non-Breaking", "Breaking", "Breaking", 
                       "Breaking", "Breaking", "Breaking"],
    "label": [None, "major", "patch", None, "patch", "patch", None, "minor", 
              "major", None, None]
})

unique_changes = df.groupby('api_spec_id')['type_of_change'].unique()

all_breaking = unique_changes.apply(lambda x: len(x)==1 and "Breaking" in x).sum()
all_non_breaking = unique_changes.apply(lambda x: len(x)==1 and "Non-Breaking" in x).sum()
at_least_one_breaking = unique_changes.apply(lambda x: "Breaking" in x).sum()
at_least_one_non_breaking = unique_changes.apply(lambda x: "Non-Breaking" in x).sum()

print('All breaking: ', all_breaking)
print('All non-breaking: ', all_non_breaking)
print('At least one breaking: ', at_least_one_breaking)
print('At least one non-breaking: ', at_least_one_non_breaking)
```

Comment: I think the code is modifying the original dataframe

Comment: I was trying it out for all the cases and i noticed the values are a bit skewed, what is the second part of the code actually doing?

Comment: It does the same as the first part but on each label, specificaly it create a dictionary counts_per_label where the keys are the unique labels and the values are the counts of rows for each label where type_of_change equals 'Breaking', excluding the first row for each api_spec_id and label

Comment: Ahh I see, okay I realize I worded my question wrong initially, this is counting rows, I want to count the unique api_spec_id where label == major and type_of_change ==Breaking for all rows  of the api_spec_id. I really apologize for this mistake

Comment: I modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
l = ['None','All Breaking, Has Breaking','All Non Breaking, Has Non Breaking','Has Breaking, Has Non Breaking']
d = df.set_index('api_spec_id')['type_of_change'].str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum().gt(0)
d = (d.mul([1,2])
 .sum(axis=1)
 .map(dict(enumerate(l)))
 .str.split(', ')
 .explode()
 .reset_index(name = 'Type')
 .groupby('Type')['api_spec_id'].agg(list)
 .to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'All Breaking': [123, 678],
 'All Non Breaking': [345],
 'Has Breaking': [123, 213, 678],
 'Has Non Breaking': [213, 345]}
```